# Action bar/Viewpager?

Tags: java, android

What is the action bar/Viewpager used for and can it be used for navigating through pages?

If it is used for navigating through screens how can i disable swiping through sections in my code so navigation can only be done by clicking on the section buttons within the action bar?

[My Java code for the action bar](http://pastebin.com/CxMCdf4F)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary goals of the action bar are to:

> Provide a dedicated space for identifying the application brand and
>   user location. This is accomplished with the app icon or logo on the
>   left side and the activity title. You might choose to remove the
>   activity title, however, if the current view is identified by a
>   navigation label, such as the currently selected tab. Provide
>   consistent navigation and view refinement across different
>   applications. The action bar provides built-in tab navigation for
>   switching between fragments. It also offers a drop-down list you can
>   use as an alternative navigation mode or to refine the current view
>   (such as to sort a list by different criteria). Make key actions for
>   the activity (such as "search", "create", "share", etc.) prominent and
>   accessible to the user in a predictable way. You can provide instant
>   access to key user actions by placing items from the options menu
>   directly in the action bar, as "action items." Action items can also
>   provide an "action view," which provides an embedded widget for even
>   more immediate action behaviors. Menu items that are not promoted to
>   an action item are available in the overflow menu, revealed by either
>   the device Menu button (when available) or by an "overflow menu"
>   button in the action bar (when the device does not include a Menu
>   button).

From http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Comment: I see so action bars are not primarily used for navigating through screens just dividing up sections of a single screen.

So how can I disable swiping between sections?

Comment: Have you tried setNavigationMode( mode )? Not sure if it is what you want though.